# How to use sql datareader to read multiple rows linked to a number from database base on textbox value c#

Tags: c#, sql

When l enter the invoice number 1992 in textbox1 which is linked to 3 rows in the database, only the last row out of 3 is displayed. I want to populate all rows linked to a particular invoice number from the database as shown in the picture using SQL datareader. Below is the code l have tried, and it shows only one row instead of three.
[image]

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ProduceID, Produce, Category, UnitPrice, UnitsOnOrder, Weight, Discount, Total FROM ordertable WHERE InvoiceNumber = '" + textBox1.Text + "'", con);
    con.Open();

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlDataReader DR;
    DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (DR.Read())
    {
        string ProduceID = (string)DR["ProduceID"].ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["ProduceID"].Value = ProduceID;
        string Produce = (string)DR["Produce"].ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["Produce"].Value = Produce;
        string Category = (string)DR["Category"].ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["Category"].Value = Category;
        string UnitPrice = (string)DR["UnitPrice"].ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["UnitPrice"].Value = UnitPrice;
        string UnitsOnOrder = (string)DR["UnitsOnOrder"].ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["UnitsOnOrder"].Value = UnitsOnOrder;
        string Weight = (string)DR["Weight"].ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["Weight"].Value = Weight;
        string Discount = (string)DR["Discount"].ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["Discount"].Value = Discount;
        string Total = (string)DR["Total"].ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["Total"].Value = Total;
    }
    con.Close();
```

Comment: What do you think will happen in a loop with `dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells.....` ? *hint* what does `Rows[0]` do?

Comment: As a side note you could also look at binding the `dataGridView1` instance which might be easier and have less code. You can usually do this in the designer but it depends on your IDE and your framework (win forms, wpf, asp.net, etc).

Comment: @Igor, I have tried binding it too, but the Column Total is not showing any value because it is throwing an exception Expression '*'  not valid. Total Column is a calculated column of UnitPrice * UnitsOnOrder. The codes above is the only one that seems to show Total Column with its corresponding values

Answer (score 1):

It should be easier to bind the DataTable to your grid

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ProduceID, Produce, Category, UnitPrice, UnitsOnOrder, Weight, Discount, Total FROM ordertable WHERE InvoiceNumber = '" + textBox1.Text + "'", con);
    con.Open();

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    con.Close();
}
```

P.S. If you want to have a manual mapping - probably you'll have to use some kind of counter

```
dataGridView1.Rows[counter]
```

Comment: i tried your code but it's returning blank datagrid

Comment: Try to split your code into the chunks. Test your query, etc. The code that you provided sets the grid in a wrong way. But I don't have any idea regarding your DB connection, etc.

Comment: @ Boris, The code i provided above is the only method that i have tried that shows the Total columns value. The others including binding datagrid to datatable are not showing Total column value. I need assistance on how to use datareader to show all rows linked to a particular invoice number.

Comment: this is my database connection                                                                                                       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Local \winSERVER;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True");
SqlCommand cmd;

Comment: So your code shows only one line? Yes? Have you tried dataGridView1.Rows[counter]. You are modifying the only first row of your table

Comment: for (counter = 0; counter < (dataGridView1.Rows.Count); counter++)
                {

                    string ProduceID = (string)DR["ProduceID"].ToString();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[counter].Cells["ProduceID"].Value = ProduceID;
                    string Produce = (string)DR["Produce"].ToString();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[counter].Cells["Produce"].Value = Produce;                    
                    
                }

Comment: the above is the code i tried. I tried the loop before and after the while (DR.Read()) but it still showing just one line

Comment: You don't need a second loop. Just a counter. And you more likely need some person to support your learning, stackoverflow is not the best place to start

Comment: Dear Boris, I may have not explained the best possible way for you to know what l want. I was referring to the code l initially posted in the question field, loop or counter doesn't seem to work for it. Before you posted your answer l have exploited almost every possible options but none work except the code l posted in the first place. It only populates the last row of a linked record. I have a column Total which is a calculated one. It works fine but It doesn't allow any value from data base to been shown where as it throws an exception 'invalid expression, type mismatch in expression *.